# Change primary group with sudo (-u) -g

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, aix

I would like to run commands on an AIX system with `sudo -i` instead of just `sudo`. This way I can make sure that any environment settings like `umask` will be those of the user I'm running the command as.

When the process started this way generates files, those files will obviously have their owner/group set to that of the user the process is run as.

Sudo has the option to specify the user *(-u)* and the group *(-g)*. However, when I try to run a command using those parameters, I get the following error:

```
 [johndoe@catchyname ~] # sudo -u 'foo' -g 'bar' ls
Sorry, user johndoe is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/ls' as foo:bar on catchyname.
```

The user is allowed to run anything on this system in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I have looked through the `sudo` documentation and searched the internet many a time, but haven't been able to get this to work yet.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man sudoers` says:

> ```
>       first Runas_List indicates which users the command may be
>       run as via sudo's -u option.  The second defines a list of
>       groups that can be specified via sudo's -g option.  If both
>       Runas_Lists are specified, the command may be run with any
>       combination of users and groups listed in their respective
>       Runas_Lists.  If only the first is specified, the command
>       may be run as any user in the list but no -g option may be
>       specified.
> ```

and further provides an example:

```
      to allow dgb to run /bin/ls with either
      the user or group set to operator:

       dgb    boulder = (operator : operator) /bin/ls
```